# Shorten integer IDs in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a site that requires people to type the ID of a user after the URL to get to the page they need. E.g. www.mysite.com/235163 where 235163 is the ID number of the profile. But is there a way to shorten numbers by introducing alpha numeric characters into the ID number so 235163 may be shortened to 1d or something a long that lines as obviously, i'm merely trying to minimize mistakes from the user inputting long numbers. Can anyone help?

Comment: Such IDs are designed to be data for internal identification purposes and are not meant to have any informational value. Why not have them use a human-readable identifier, like a username?

Comment: maybe you can use decimal to hex conversation.

Comment: It doesn't shorten it (thus I'm not supplying this as an answer), but maybe you could provide the IDs with dashes every 2 or so digits, so split the number up and thus make it easier for the user to see errors typed in; e.g. 23-51-63. Then just strip non-numeric digits from the data to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first thing that springs to mind is to use dechex() to convert from decimal into hexadecimal, so in this case 235163 would become 3969b, and obviously very easy to translate back to the id using hexdec()

```
echo hexdec(235163); // 3969b
echo dechex('3969b') // 235163
```

Or you could use base_convert() to convert to base 36, giving:

```
echo base_convert(235163, 10, 36); // 51gb
echo base_convert('51gb', 36, 10); // 235163
```

Comment: Thanks Chris that is one possibility but my concern is 234163 should be able to be expressed by a hex code much lower than 3969b I wonder if there is any way of doing it, if not then this is a great substitute

Comment: Convert to base 36? Only 4 digits for that ID

Comment: I recommend base 36 (a-z and 0-9) rather than hexadecimal / base 16 (0-9 and a-f).

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar challenge; my solution was to convert the base-10 number (decimal) into base-64.  Base-64 uses other characters (A-Z, a-z, etc) to represent the number; this effectively reduces the number of characters needed to represent the number.  This "shortened number" can then be used in the URL.

For PHP, Paul Greg [created some code](http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/base_conversion/base_conversion.php) that handles converting from base-10 to another base.  I also blogged about [converting row ID's to Base-64 for short url's](http://gabesumner.com/how-to-create-short-links-using-c-and-database-ids) on my personal blog.  However, my code utilizes C#; if you're interested in using this approach then use Paul's code to recreate this for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dechex($id)`](http://php.net/dechex).